# Warning: field is used but is never assigned a non-"null" value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have implemented a Java EE page which connects to an inventory webservice. I have implemented an inventory controller as shown below:

```
public class InventoryController {
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate inventoryWsTemplate;

...

}
```

*inventoryWsTemplate* is declared as a bean in web-servlet.xml.

The program works but I'm getting a warning that says:

> field is used but is never assigned a non-"null" value

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `SuppressWarnings` annotation:

```
@Autowired
@SuppressWarnings("null")
private WebServiceTemplate inventoryWsTemplate;
```

*Normally* I'd add a comment to justify the annotation (e.g. `// Used by guice`) but in this case coming hot on the heels of an `Autowired` annotation, I don't think it's necessary.

EDIT: I can't reproduce the problem on Eclipse to start with, so I'm not sure which annotation value is required. You should check the list of supported annotation values for your compiler.

Comment: When to use what? (Which is better? Depends on what?) `//` or `@SuppressWarnings`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun When ever you get this warning,And you don't want to remove  the declaration :).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I'll clarify my answer - I meant I'd add a comment *with the annotation*.

Comment: so the way i declare the webservicetemplate is correct? but why is it giving the warning?

Comment: @nuttynibbles: The warning describes the cause pretty clearly - you've got a private field and you're never setting it yourself. The compiler has a reasonable expectation that that means it'll never get set. It's *actually* getting set by reflection, but that's pretty unusual and beyond the compiler's knowledge.

Comment: well i supprised and it still have the warning. it also says unnecessary @SuppressWarning("unused")

Comment: @nuttynibbles: Which IDE are you using? It's possible that it needs a slightly different annotation value.

Comment: im using eclipse java ide for web developers. verson: indigo service release 2

Comment: @nuttynibbles: Interesting. I can't reproduce it in Kepler :( See if using `"null"` fixes it for you instead of `"unused"`

Comment: null is nt working either. its strange because i removed the earlier suppressed and now it didnt complain. but i added the suppress to other codes and its not working.

Comment: @nuttynibbles: Hmm. If you can come up with a short but *complete* class which demonstrates the problem, it'll be easier to help you. Clean build, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like suppressing warnings, you can change `private` to any other access modifier.  Package-private probably being the best choice (besides private).

Comment: hmm, changing visibility of an instance variable just so there is no warning anymore is not a good idea. The state of your object is then accessible for the whole package.